# Workarounds for Flash bug when drawing large shapes?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

When you use Graphics object to draw very large shape(that does not fit in 10000x10000 pixels) stroke width may become much wider than value specified in lineStyle function.

What are the workarounds to overcome this?

For now I have only two options:
1. When drawing line you can split it into several lines. However this trick does work  only for drawing lines, polylines and polygons. There is no way to apply this to drawing circles and ellipses. Well, we can approximate circles via bezier curves, but this approach seems to be very inefficient.
2. Perform manual cliping. But this require manual implementation of different cliping techiniques, and I  think ActionScript does not suit well for this sort of task. And again there is need to approximate visible parts of large circles.

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest are you using the **scrollRect** as this will prevent anything not in the view port from being drawn and will hopefully help you solve this.

Andrew

Comment: Just tried it, nothing changed - same issue. I also tried drawing to bitmap - same issue.